# Node.JS - Handling incoming requests with Async functions

Tags: node.js

As far as I understand Node.js is single threaded and handles each request one at a time. However, when making asynchronous calls it should be able to deal with new requests while the callbacks haven't been called yet.

So when I make 3 request simultaneously to the following server implementation, why does it wait for 10 sec for the first response, and then 20 for the 2nd, and 30 for the 3rd...?

```
var express = require('express');    
    var app = express();
    app.get('*', function(req, res) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            res.end('done')
        },10000)
    });
    app.listen(8000);
```

Comment: The code looks OK. There is something else limiting simultaneous connections from single IP, whether it is browser, or server I am not sure.

Comment: Thanks alandarev, tried it from different browsers, and it was indeed asynchronous, you're correct.

Comment: Your code responds to each request with a 10 second delay. If you send 3 requests directly one after another, you will get 3 responses after 10 seconds, directly one after another. If you see different behavior then it's not because of the code you show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking this using your browser, you should test it with another node.js script... For example, using this script:

```
var http = require('http');

function test(timestamp) {
    http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000',function(res) {
           console.log(new Date() - timestamp);
    });
}


for (var i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++) {
    test(new Date().getTime());
}
```

I get the following result (Using your code as http server):

```
> node test.js
10032
10029
10029
10029
10030
```

So it seems that the problem wasn't on you're node.js code.